# java rally api , not able to create testset in specific iteration and release , getting created in unscheduled iteration

Tags: rally

```
JsonObject newTS = new JsonObject();
newTS.addProperty("Workspace", "/workspace/25194919975");
newTS.addProperty("Name", "name");
newTS.addProperty("Project", "/project/81223493876");
newTS.addProperty("Tags", tagName);
newTS.addProperty("Release.Name", releaseID);
newTS.addProperty("Iteration.Name", iterationID);
newTS.addProperty("projectScopeUp", false);
newTS.addProperty("projectScopeDown", true);
newTS.addProperty("fetch", true);
newTS.addProperty("rankTo", "BOTTOM");
newTS.add("TestCases", testCaseList);

CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testset",newTS) 
CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
```

Results:

```
{"CreateResult": { "_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": [], "Warnings": ["It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources.", "Ignored JSON element testset.Tags.Name during processing of this request.", "Ignored JSON element testset.Release.Name during processing of this request.", "Ignored JSON element testset.Iteration.Name during processing of this request.", "Ignored JSON element testset.projectScopeUp during processing of this request.", "Ignored JSON element testset.projectScopeDown during processing of this request.", "Ignored JSON element testset.fetch during processing of this request.", "Ignored JSON element testset.rankTo during processing of this request."]
```

Comment: Can help would be appriciate

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to set Iteration and Release by object reference rather than by name- just like you are with Project.

```
newTS.addProperty("Iteration", "/iteration/12345");
newTS.addProperty("Release", "/release/23456");
```

A few other things as well:

Setting `projectScopeUp` and `projectScopeDown` has no effect on a create.

`fetch` should be set on the request:

```
createRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("true"));
```

`rankTo` should be added as a param on the request:

```
createRequest.addParam("rankTo", "Bottom");
```

Comment: Hi Kyle,Thanks for the quick resonse 
i am getting following error

Error:
Cannot parse object reference from "/release/release 2.2"

Comment: A ref is of the format /<type>/<objectid>.  It looks like you're still specifying the name...